# Allow tag edits while suggested question edits are pending

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, edits

I follow some tags and many questions are wrongly tagged with them. In these cases, I don't care about some formatting or grammar changes someone suggested and possibly read a long post that I'm not interested in and consider every change, just to be able to remove a wrong tag. I neither want to accept, nor reject the edit, I just care about the tag field, which should be independent of the main question text in this regard. Currently my only possibilities are spending time on a question that doesn't interest me, blindly accepting or rejecting random edits or not making the tag edit.

To be clear: I'm talking about Gaming SE, where I can edit questions without going through peer review.

Comment: Btw, I currently usually just blindly accept these edits if they look minor at first glance. But that's definitely not good for the site.